# MSMQ, Asynchronous Reading and Acknowledgement

Tags: c++, msmq

I need to develop an application which will read messages from MSMQ asynchronously. I found good examples of this the official one being

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms701332(v=vs.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms701349(v=vs.85).aspx

But the additional requirement is MSMQ should keep the message in message queue until I send acknowledgement message. Is there a way to do that? If yes, is there a example out there which demonstrates this?

One more advanced requirement also is that there might be more than one receiver of the same message (or subscriber of the same message queue) and I want MSMQ to delete the message only after all of the subscribers have read the message. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance,
-Neel.